# IF/ELSE structure in mysql SP not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure which enrols a student in a table. But before doing so, it checks weather the student is already present, if it does then no insertion takes place.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN sid varchar(6), IN us varchar(20), IN pswd varchar(20))
BEGIN
declare temp varchar(20);
declare x int;
declare y int;
set temp=(select username from login_student where s_id=sid);
IF(temp == NULL)
THEN insert into login_student values(sid, us, pswd);
ELSEIF (temp != NULL)
THEN set x=x+1; //have written it randomly
ELSE
     set y=y+1; //have written it randomly
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

login_student table schema is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE login_student 
(s_id varchar(6),
 username varchar(20),
 password varchar(20)
);
```

It's giving me some syntax error, can any one mark out the mistake please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems I see:

1. You need to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` instead of `== NULL` and `!= NULL`
2. You are using the wrong syntax for MySQL comments. Use `--` not `//`

It should also be noted that you will never reach the ELSE in this case, since temp is either `NULL` or `NOT NULL`, so you could simplify it to an IF/ELSE if you want.

And I would recommend using `SELECT ... INTO` instead of `SET` to set the temp value.

Putting it all together:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test //
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN sid varchar(6), IN us varchar(20), IN pswd varchar(20))
BEGIN
declare temp varchar(20);
declare x int;
declare y int;
select username into temp from login_student where s_id=sid;
IF(temp IS NULL)
THEN insert into login_student values(sid, us, pswd);
ELSEIF (temp IS NOT NULL)
THEN set x=x+1; -- have written it randomly
ELSE
     set y=y+1; -- have written it randomly
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to get the text of an error, but I think it should be:

```
IF(temp IS NULL)
    THEN insert into login_student values(sid, us, pswd);
ELSEIF (temp IS NOT NULL)
    THEN set x=x+1; //have written it randomly
ELSE
    set y=y+1; //have written it randomly
END IF;
```